# How to execute a command in a buffer with a specific name in the background?

Tags: vim

I'm currently doing the following, but it makes the current window switch to the buffer in question, which is disruptive:

```
let current_buffer = bufname("%")
buffer NERD_tree_1
normal R
exec "buffer" current_buffer
```

Is there a way to execute a command in a buffer with a specific name (in this case `NERD_tree_1`) in the background?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no such mechanism, especially not for `:normal`, which executes commands in the current window.

I see two options:

1. Since you're already relying on plugin internals (the `NERD_tree_1` buffer name), you could further delve into the plugin and directly modify it / its data structures to achieve your goal. Note that this is a brittle solution that is susceptible to future plugin updates, and therefore not recommended.
2. Completely rely on the plugin's external interface (i.e. replace the `:buffer` commands with `:NERDTreeToggle`), and live with the side effects of the plugin briefly activating.